# Can't connect to websocket server in symfony

Tags: symfony, sockets, networking, websocket, chat

I have a problem with server WebSocket after deploying in some hosting I can not connect to the server.  I tried some checker pages to see if that server is running, but the same issue, please any help?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally would make a list of common problems and the differences between the running server and non-running server. For instance, I'd check if my non-running server has the "Socket Support" enabled by checking the phpinfo() function and so on.